# <MATLAB> How can I save huge data to .txt file?

Tags: matlab, printf

I made a  865850 by 4464 matrix.

Then I need to save it to a .txt file.

For that, I use fprintf, but I met a hard obstacle....

There are 4464 columns. How can I designate their formatspec?

They are all integers.

Now I know just one way...

fprintf(fid, '%10d %10d.....%10d', Zeros); (4464times..)

Is the only way to save them?

Thank you~!!

```
clear all; close all;

loop = 1;
Zeros = zeros(15000, 4464);

fileID = fopen('data2.txt','r');

while loop < 4200
    Data = fscanf(fileID, '%d %d %d:%d %d\n', [5, 100000]);
    Data = Data';
    DataA = Data(:,1);
    DataB = Data(:,2);
    DataC = Data(:,3);
    DataD = Data(:,4);
    DataE = Data(:,5);


    for m=1:100000
        r = DataA(m);
        c = ((DataB(m)-1)*24*6 + DataC(m)*6 + DataD(m))+1;
        Zeros(r,c) = DataE(m);            
    end
    for n=1:4464
        Zeros1{n}=Zeros(:, n);
        fileID2 = fopen('result.txt','a');
        fprintf(fileID2, '%10d %10d\n ', Zeros1{1}, Zeros1{2});
    end
   fclose(fileID2);
   loop = loop + 1;
```

end

Comment: [`dlmwrite`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)?

Comment: if you really want to use `fprintf`, you can build your format specifier with `repmat`. Something like : `formatspec=repmat('%10d ',1,4464)`. I have to agree with @MarcusMuller though, think if text format is really what you need, binary would be more convenient for this size of data set.

Answer (score 2):

don't use printf with the whole row. Use the CSV export, or iterate over each element of each row and print it isolatedly.

I frequently like to add that for data of this size, textual storage is a **bad** idea. No one will ever open this in a text editor and think "Oh, this is practical". Everyone will have a bad time carrying around hundreds of megabytes of unnecessary file size. simply use the `savemat` methods to store the data if you plan to open it in matlab, or use a binary format, for example by just doing `fwrite` on the data to a file with a sensible binary representation of your numbers.

Comment: I prefer @HelloLemmy's answer for saving text data, but you get my vote for telling the OP that this is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use the built-in MATLAB ASCII save format (instead of `printf`):

```
>> foo = magic( 4 )

foo =

16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1

>> save( 'foo.txt', '-ascii', 'foo' )
```